# Need help understanding how to use a python package I made

Tags: python, package

I recently created and published a python package called ADCT.

Link to package as zip download so you can see what I mean: https://pypi.org/project/ADCT/#modal-close

I went ahead and published it and I was able to pip install it on my local machine. In the package, there is an object itself called ADCT. What code snippet, other than "import ADCT" do I run to call the object ADCT? Do I have to rename the object to something else since it could be a collision error? I know this is embarrassing since its my package but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package and the object will likely to end up in different namespaces. Example:

```
from ADCT import DataObj
adct_instance = DataObj.ADCT()
```

Another way to deal with duplicated names (not very helpful in this case, just for the reference) is to use `import .. as`, e.g.:

```
import ADCT as ADCT_package
adct_instance = ADCT_package.DataObj.ADCT()
```

Comment: Thanks you Marat, I appreciate both your accuracy and haste.